# Django: How to show a picture from my database in a template?

Tags: python, django, database, image

I'm using `Django`, and trying to display a picture from my database. However, I am unable to.

Most of the code I am using is from [this article](https://www.etutorialspoint.com/index.php/356-how-to-display-image-from-database-in-django).

This is my code.

My `model("ingredient")` uses:

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
pictureLink = models.ImageField(upload_to="media")
```

The pictureLink I provided in my database is:

> C:\Users"Me"\Desktop"project"\image\leaves.png

My `views.py` contains:

```
def say_hello(request):
    allimages = Ingredient.objects.all()  
    return render(request, 'hello.html', {'images' : allimages})
```

My HTML code is the following:

```
{% for img in images %}  
  <tr>
    <td>{{img.title}}</td>
    <td><img src="{{ingredient.pictureLink.url}}" width="120"/></td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

In `settings.py` I put the following:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'image') 
MEDIA_URL = '/image/'
```

Where am I making a mistake? I'm a beginner with Django, so all feedback is appreciated!

Comment: did you serve `media` in urls?

Comment: @HamidrezaKhorammfar this is my main urls.py: urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('playground/', include('playground.urls')),
    path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Answer (score 0):

first change your `settings.py`

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
STATIC_URL = '/media/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (BASE_DIR / 'media/static', ) 
STATIC_ROOT = 'media/staticfiles/'
```

second create a folder named `media` in your path

then add this to `urlpatterns` in your app `urls.py` to this:

```
 url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)/$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}, name = 'media'),
```

Do not forget to import these in the `urls.py` file in your application folder

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.static import serve
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Still doesn't seem to work though... I have changed the settings, added a folder to my path (~\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe) and added the urlpatterns. When i run my code and runserver i do get a picture icon, so it knows there has to be a picture, but the picture I want to display is still not there.

Comment: create `media` folder in your project path side by side of manage.py i mean and try add again photo in your path

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help, I'm afraid it's still not working though... I now have a media folder at the same level of manage.py and the apps. In the folder i have the picture named leaves.png. In my database I have the pictureLink (varChar) collumn filled in with "media/leaves.png". Do you think there is something wrong with my database or is the error in my code? My apologies for taking up so much of your time

Comment: @TicovanHoek If you want, you can send me your project so that I can fix it

Comment: That is extremely kind of you, but I wouldn't want to bother you with it. I will keep looking through the documentation to try and find a solution. Thanks for the offer though!